# Pointer to a void * function C++

Tags: c++, pthreads, function-pointers, void-pointers

I am trying to call pointer to a `void *` function inside the main method and the compiler is saying `assigning to 'funcptr<g>' from incompatible type 'void *(void *)`. `hello` function is actually an argument to `pthread_create` function. That's why it is `void *` function. How can I create a function pointer to a `void *` function?

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <pthread.h> 

using namespace std; 

template<typename T> 
using funcptr = void (*T::*)(void *); // I think it is wrong here.

class m { 
public: 
    template <typename T> 
    struct my_struct { 
        funcptr<T> ptr; 
    };
}; 

class g { 
public: 
    static void *hello(void *); 
}; 

int main() { 
    struct m::my_struct<g> h; 
    h.ptr = g::hello; // Error here

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what the new way of doing this is but I always just did `typedef void (*funcptr)(void *);`

Comment: Since `hello` is a static function, you don't need to template `funcptr`: `using funcptr = void *(*)(void *);`
For class m: 
`class m { 
public:
 struct my_struct {
  funcptr ptr;
 };
};`
In main:
`struct m::my_struct h; 
h.ptr = &g::hello; // Take the address of hello`

Comment: Use std::thread, don't use OS threads directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I create a function pointer to a void * function?
>   `hello` is not a member function, but it's a *static* function.

So your `funcptr` should be as follows:

```
// No template needed.
using funcptr = void* (*)(void *)
```

Note that `hello` is declared with **static**, [meaning that it's no longer a member function to `g`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static#Explanation).

> Static members of a class are **not** associated with the objects of the class.

So using `void (*T::*)(void *)` to cull non-member functions is incorrect.

If you're allowed to use a compiler that supports C++11, you don't even need to *manually deduct* its type anymore, using [decltype](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype):

```
// decltype deducts its exact type for you.
using funcptr = decltype(&g::hello);

class m 
{ 
public: 
    struct my_struct 
    { 
        funcptr ptr; 
    };
};
```

FYI, since `hello` does not have its definition, you might encounter a linkage error. To prevent that, I assumed that there's some implementation inside:

```
static void *hello(void *) 
{ 
    // Meaningless, but..
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

if you're using C++11, you can use `std::function<>` which just bothers about the return type and parameters of the function and not where they are defined and what are its type.

Here is the code using `std::function<>`

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <functional>
#include <pthread.h> 

using namespace std; 

class m { 
public: 
    template <typename T> 
    struct my_struct { 
        function<void*(void*)> ptr;
    };
}; 

class g { 
public: 
    static void *hello(void *) {
        cout<<"Hello.."<<endl;
    }
}; 

int main() { 
    struct m::my_struct<g> h; 
    h.ptr = g::hello;
    h.ptr(nullptr);

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `std::function` is overkill when only a simple function pointer is needed. Plus, there is no answer to the question: "How can I create a function pointer to a void * function?"